# HDD doesn't properly work

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, hardware-failure, boot

Recently, while I was installing windows 7, I tried to re-partition my 750 gb hdd.
There were following partitions inside my HDD:

1. Swap
2. Ubuntu
3. Backtrack
4. System reserved for Windows 7
5. Windows 7

I tried to remove old windows 7's reserved partition (which is 100 mb). And my laptop suddenly stuck and there was no way to continue installation process but restart.

When I restarted my laptop, BIOS was detecting HDD as device but nothing else. Just black screen.

I rejected hdd from my laptop and tested on another pc.

I tried to fix this problem using bunch of software such as: Gparted (which stuck during loading process, and alerted message "... kernel panic ...") , Mini XP (doesn't see any hdd device), Windows 7 (alse didn't see any hdd device).

What do you suggest? Thx in advance for your time.

Comment: Sounds like you may want to run a hard drive test.

Answer (score 0):

Try using WinDFT and run an Extended Test on your drive. If that passes, erase the disk and then try to repartition